# Indexing xml file into solr using XPathEntityProcessor - unable to index some tags

Tags: xml, xpath, solr, dataimporthandler

Using the [XPathEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_XML.2FHTTP_Datasource), I am indexing following xml file (just an example):

```
<shop>
 <vegitable>
 ....
 </vegitable>
 <fruit>
      <property>
        <kind>apple</kind>
        <value>3.08</value>
        <from>USA</from>
      </property>
      <property>
        <kind>banana</kind>
        <value>8.5</value>
        <from>CA</from>
      </property>  
      <property>
        <kind>painaple</kind>
        <value>102.8</value>
        <from>CA</from>
      </property>
 </fruit>
 ....
 ....
 ....
 </shop>
```

I wish to store apple property in one field and all other properties into another field, so that i can use it for view purpose.
Bellow is my solr-config.xml file, but solr doesn't process these 2 fields.

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
        <document>
        <entity name="drug"
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                stream="true"
                forEach="/shop/"
                url="/data/shop.xml"
                transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer"
                >
                ....
                ....
            <field column="apple-imported-form" xpath="/shop/fruit/property/[kind='apple']/from"/>
            <field column="apple-imported-value" xpath="/shop/fruit/property/[kind='apple']/value"/>
        </entity>
       </document>
</dataConfig>
```

while reading document on [XPathEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_XML.2FHTTP_Datasource) on solr, i found following lines:

> The XPathEntityProcessor implements a streaming parser which supports
>   a subset of xpath syntax.  Complete xpath syntax is not supported but
>   most of the common use cases are covered.

But there is nothing mentioned about what things not covered while from Xpath. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I see you have bad xml <fruit> no ending </fruit>

Comment: Also I don't know solr but maybe error is because bad xpath. Maybe you can change it to /shop/fruit/property[descendant::kind='apple']/from

Comment: thanks Darka for your input, please find corrected xml, also I tried with your given syntax but it is not working n solr, I am trying to parse the xml into solr document, which looks quite impossible.

Comment: what if you simply try if it works /shop/fruit/property/kind and /shop/fruit/property/from

Answer (score 0):

I found this in documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

The XPathEntityProcessor implements a streaming parser which supports a subset of xpath syntax. Complete xpath syntax is not supported but most of the common use cases are covered as follows:

```
   xpath="/a/b/subject[@qualifier='fullTitle']"
   xpath="/a/b/subject/@qualifier"
   xpath="/a/b/c"
   xpath="//a/..."
   xpath="/a//b..."
```

I also tried xpath as below but it didn't work. (My Solr version is: 5.2)

```
   xpath="/a/b/subject[@qualifier='fullTitle']/id"
```

It seems we have to declare qualifier last.